# Obtener resultado de consulta sql para enviar datos con setter

Tags: java, spring

Estoy desarrollando en spring soy nueva en este tema de spring framework en java y tengo una duda sobre resultado de una consulta sql a la db.

Estoy realizando la consulta en mysql con procedure con condicional where y los resultados de esa columna necesito enviarlos al objeto usuario como se hacia en java jsp -> `usuario.setNombres(rs.getString(2));` pasaba a nombre de usuario el resultado de la columna dos en la db con el resultSet, como puedo realizar esto en spring ?? sin usar una lista para obtener el resultado como lo tengo en este momento.
Al ejecutar la consulta me muestra sugerencias que realmente nose como se usan y son estos  queryForObject y ResultSetExtractor, creo que el que necesitaria seria el resulsetextracor pero nose como se usa.
mi codigo esta asi en este momento

```
public List consultarUsuario(String id) {
        List consuList = null;
        try {
            consuList = jdbc.queryForList("CALL Us_InfoPerfil (?)", id);
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

        return consuList;
    }
```